# Usage of 'Could' and 'Would' in non-past tense sentense

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Could someone explain me why we should use "Could"and "Would" in this sentence? can we use "Can" and "Will" instead?

"Is this report something that your team *could* handle for me?  Please review the attached and let me know.  I can’t imagine it *would* take more than 10 minutes a week".

Thanks
santhosha

Comment: Such a question has already been asked here. You could do a search to review the answer(s) as well. In fact, that's what is recommended before you post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional tense is being used as a form of politeness. By expressing a modicum of doubt about the outcome, the respondent is offered the opportunity to refuse politely.

"Is this report something that your team *can* handle for me?"

"Nope, we're too busy."

versus

"Is this report something that your team *could* handle for me?"

"We *would* help you but unfortunately the team is very busy.

Answer (score 1):

"could" softens a request, makes it sound less demanding.

A boss might say, "Can you finish it by today?", which adds an implicit demand that he'd like it done by today. A request for a favour is better asked with "could".

*Expressing a conjecture, opinion, or hope:*

'I would imagine that they’re home by now'
'I guess some people would consider it brutal'
'I would have to agree'

(More examples: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/would)